# jQuery trigger an event when specific element is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to globally catch whenever some element (f.e. `textarea`) is rendered on the page to do something with it. Element could be inserted by AJAX request too.

```
// This is just an example of functionality I want to achieve
// Not a real code
$(document).on('render', 'textarea', function() {
    $(this).whatEver();
});
```

I know about document's `ajaxComplete` method, but I am looking for some more generic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to do it using [livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) plugin which repetitively checks for elements in dom. So I can do following:

```
$('textarea').livequery(function() { $(this).whatEver(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('#container').on('DOMNodeInserted ', 'textarea', function(){
$(this).whatEver();
})
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 //Loaded...
 $('textarea').whatEver();
});
```

Comment: `DOMNodeInserted` detects only direct children of the container, therefore it does not detect nested textareas. `$(document).ready` does not work for textareas loaded by ajax.